# Adding an ImageView array to a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-imageview

I am trying to add a series of images to the current `RelativeLayout` at runtime below another `TextView`. So far, I get it to display partially correct, but not exactly right.  I can't get them to move to another row. I hope someone can give me a hand and show me the correct way.  The series of image will appear below this `TextView`(`R.id.date`):

```
     TextView date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);

    //// image view start //////
    int photos = Integer.parseInt(total_photo);
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_b);
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView (this);
        imageView.setId(i);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo_frame);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 0);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setMaxHeight(80);
        imageView.setMaxWidth(80);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.date);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imageView.getId() - 1);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        mainLayout.addView(imageView);
    }
```

Right now, it only display total photo quantity - 1 (i.e.: when there is 5, it only display 4); and I would like to get each row to display 5 and will move to the next row immediately if it reach 6, 11, 16....etc.   This layout is nested inside a `ScrollView` and in a `RelativeLayout` because I have quite a few views in it. So, I will have to stick with `RelativeLayout` for this.

Comment: I'd suggest moving to a GridView as your parent layout, and setting up your RelativeLayout as the view to inflate into your GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you're trying to do, see if the code below position the `ImageViews` like you want(I don't know how efficient it is):

```
    private static final int ROW_ITEMS = 5; // 5 ImageViews per row

    // ...
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_b);
            int limit = 13; // I assume that limit is the number of ImageView that you'll put in the layout
            int rows = limit / ROW_ITEMS; // the number of rows that results from limit
            int leftOver = limit % ROW_ITEMS; // see if we have incomplete rows
            if (leftOver != 0) {
                rows += 1;
            }
            int id = 1000; // the ids of the ImageViews 1000, 1001, 1002 etc
            int belowId = R.id.date; // this id will be used to position the ImageView on another row
            while (rows > 0) {
                int realItemsPerRow = ROW_ITEMS;
                if (leftOver != 0 & rows == 1) {
                    realItemsPerRow = Math.min(ROW_ITEMS, leftOver);
                }           
                for (int i = 0; i < realItemsPerRow; i++) {
                    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                    imageView.setId(id);
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 0);
                    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    imageView.setMaxHeight(80);
                    imageView.setMaxWidth(80);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                    } else {
                        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imageView.getId() - 1);
                    }
                    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, belowId);              
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    mainLayout.addView(imageView);
                    id++;
                }           
                belowId = id - 1; 
                rows--; 
            }
```

Also, as kcoppock already said in his comment, it might be worth looking at the `GridView` for efficiency.

Comment: what if i want to add a textview below these images? below..?

Comment: @SArumik Below the last row of images? Below each row images? Below each image?

Comment: @SArumik After the `while` loop, setup that `TextView`, set the desired `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` and use the rule: `relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, belowId - 1);`. See if this is what you want.